# Sorting a file by a specific field

Tags: python, linux, unix, sorting, system-administration

I have a file that has the following format:
12345 TAB_HERE Name : The Actual Name TAB_HERE 6785

eg.

---

```
1001020 Name : SMITH S ANNALOLA     14570
5701061 Name : MATTHEW SANDY HILL   6440
7001083 Name : TANYA MORRISON MILLER    14406
```

---

I want to sort by the last field of numbers.

I'd prefer a simple one line python solution or a linux tool based solution.

I tried using sort -k 3,3n but it did not work.
And I can't seem to write a single line python code that I can run as python -c "code here"

I looked at the following but to no avail:

http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/18359-how-do-i-specify-tab-field-separator-sort.html

http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/30450-sort-third-column-n-command.html

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/unix-sort-on-multiple-fields-598813/

Comment: You looked at [`awk`](http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-awk.html)?

Comment: @kevlar1818: why awk? with python it is also elementary

Comment: @Ayos - did you try the `-t` option to sort to set your field separator - e.g. `sort -t'<tab>' -k 3,3n`? By default, `sort` sees any spaces or tabs as a separator.

Comment: @twalberg According to the `sort` [manpage](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_sort.htm), the default separator is on word boundary, which seems fine in this case.

Comment: @IgorChubin I could turn that question back at you and say: Why python? With awk it is also elementary, is built-in with Linux, and can be done from the command line in one command.

Comment: @kevlar1818: you are right, but that was the author, not I, who wanted to solve the task in python. I perfectly understand that perl, awk, ruby could help to solve the task not worse than python. I just wanted to say that python is here as good as awk and when you are already with python you need not change to awk just to write this oneliner

Comment: @kevlar1818 - You're correct in that, but going with that definition, it wasn't field 3 that the OP wanted to sort on - based on the `sort -k 3,3n` test, I was presuming that they were expecting fields to be delimited by tabs, not whitespace, punctuation, etc. Probably could have worded that comment a bit better, though.

Comment: @twalberg It doesn't seem to accept sort -t '\t' and throws an error saying multi-line character '\\t' or something similar.

Comment: @IgorChubin I don't know awk yet, So I'm using python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick solution:

```
import sys
print "".join(sorted(sys.stdin.readlines(), key=lambda x:int(x.split()[-1])))
```

This solution has some disadvantages. For example, it will not work if you have lines without number at the last field, or if you want sort the data not by the last field but by everything else. In this case you must use regular expressions (`re` module) and descrive the field that you want to use for sorting in the `key` function.

Comment: We can also just do `sorted(sys.stdin, key=...)` which avoid the creation of an additional list.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same answer, but it can't be expressed as a single line as requested in the question.

Comment: @Mark: You can always do `python -c "import sys; ..."`

Comment: @NiklasB., I couldn't get the semicolon to work for me, it gives a syntax error. I'm not sure of the rules for semicolon usage.

Comment: @Mark: I'm using Python 2.7. Probably you are using your shell wrong?

Comment: @Mark: `python2 -c "import sys; print ''.join(sorted(sys.stdin))" <<< test` works in GNU Bash and zsh. It works with Python 3 as well (and I don't see why it shouldn't).

Comment: @Mark: of course you can use ; in Python. Don't forget to escape the character from shell

Comment: Discovered my problem, I was trying a `for` loop instead of the `join`. I was also testing within IDLE on Windows which might make a difference.

Comment: @Mark: Yeah, it seems that `import sys; for x in [1,2,3]: print x` is not valid Python. I wonder why that is, seeing that the parts separated by the semicolon are both valid lines of Python. **EDIT:** http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html explains the syntax. The semicolon has precedence of the colon.

Answer (score 2):

Python one liner:

```
cat file | python -c 'import sys; print "".join(sorted(sys.stdin.readlines(), key=lambda x:int(x.split()[-1])))'
```

My guess why the other python example won't work as a one liner is that he is using " to mark up the code and to invoke the join()...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the --key parameter for the sort command counts the space characters.

```
sort -k7n
```

worked for me..

Comment: I'm guessing the name could consist of more or less than 3 parts, so this is likely to fail on real input.

Comment: As @MarkRansom said the name could have more or less than 3 parts, also I'm trying to use tab as the delimiter, not a space. I especially checked that there are only two tabs instead of one tab being treated as 4 spaces.
But the fact that -k7n work tells me that sort seems to use tab OR space simultaneously, which is strange since other similar utils like cut use only one at a time.